# IMagickImage.Crop() causes image to be blurry

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have the following C# code:

```
MagickImage pdfPage = MyCodeToGetPage();
String barcodePng = "tmp.png"
MagickGeometry barcodeArea = new MagickGeometry(350, 153, 208, 36);
IMagickImage barcodeImg = pdfPage.Clone();
barcodeImg.Crop(barcodeArea);
barcodeImg.Write(barcodePng);
```

It creates a tmp.png file that is displayed in the lower barcode below:

[image]

The problem is that tmp.png file is fuzzy and my barcode detection logic will not detect the barcode.  You can see the upper image is clear and the lines are not merged.

The title says that Crop() is causing the problem, but it could also be the Write().

How do I crop the barcode out of the pdf without making tmp.png fuzzy?

This was not a problem when the source document is a .tif.  More precisely, if I convert the .pdf to a .tif and then crop it the .png is clear enough that the barcode can be detected.  I want to eliminate the intermediate .tif as it used a clumsy printer driver to convert.

Comment: When you read your PDF, you are rasterizing at the default 72 dpi. That is not producing enough quality. You need to rasterize at a larger density (then optionally resize down), then crop or crop at the higher density. So you need to specify a larger density before reading in the PDF. If you post a link to your PDF, I can show you how in ImageMagick command line.

Comment: @fmw42 my screenshot is showing the 72 dpi image as the upper barcode.  you can see the lines are crisp.  it has been sufficient quality for years when it is converted to a .tiff and then cropped.  Simply cropping should not make the image fuzzy.  Before I work on increasing the dpi as a solution I want to make cropping not make the image fuzzy.

Comment: Has your Ghostscript changed versions? ImageMagick uses Ghostscript. If its version has changed or any arguments to it has changed then that could be the cause. Does it happen with all PDFs or just this one?

Comment: This program is specific for processing PDFs that are all generated the same way.  I have not tried other .PDFs but it is not relevant because this program will only run with the PDFs that I generate from other code.

Comment: Ghostscript has not changed.

Comment: If you post your PDF, I can rasterize it and see if I get the same blurry result.

Comment: I appreciate the offer; The pdf has private information on it.  I will have to figure out how to generate one with dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested in your answer below:

Adding density on the read was what I had first suggested in my comment to your question. It increases the size of the rasterized version of the input. It is like scanning at a higher density. What I typically do in ImageMagick is to read the pdf at 4x nominal density, which is 4x72=288, then resize down by 1/4=25%. This will generally give a much better quality to your your result. So the command that I use in command line ImageMagick would be:

```
convert -density 288 input.pdf -resize 25% result.suffix
```

I would also add that Ghostscript cannot handle CMYK PDFs that have transparency. So one must change the colorspace to sRGB before reading the pdf file. So in this case, it would be:

```
convert -density 288 -colorspace sRGB input.pdf -resize 25% result.suffix
```

Sorry, I do not code C++, so perhaps I misunderstand, but I do not understand why increasing the density before reading in a TIFF would make any difference.

Comment: As promised I am giving you the win even tho you are not showing C# code.  You did have the right answer, I just did not know how to translate it to C# code to test.

Answer (score 0):

This URL had the answer:
http://www.jiajianhudong.com/question/642668.html

To fix it I changed my code to this:

```
MagickImage pdfPage = MyCodeToGetPage();
String barcodePng = "tmp.png"
MagickGeometry barcodeArea = new MagickGeometry(350, 153, 208, 36);
IMagickImage barcodeImg = pdfPage.Clone();
barcodeImg.ColorType = ColorType.Bilevel;
barcodeImg.Depth = 1;
barcodeImg.Alpha(AlphaOption.Off);
barcodeImg.Crop(barcodeArea);
barcodeImg.Write(barcodePng);
```

And the most critical part of fixing was to change:

```
using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffPageCollection.Read(tifName);
```

to

```
var settings = new MagickReadSettings { Density = new Density(200) };

using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffPageCollection.Read(tifName, settings);
```

If someone wants to copy my answer and add a clear reason why adding Density on the read fixes the problem I will give them the answer.